# Visual Studio Team Services Build Package Restore failing with project.json netstandard1.0 target

Tags: .net, azure-devops, .net-core, nuget-package-restore, azure-pipelines

I have recently updated my portable class libraries to target .NET Core, using project.json, and the new netstandard1.0 framework moniker.  My understanding is that this is supported now in Nuget 3.4.
I have the following project.json for my project:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.0": {}
  }
}
```

This builds great from Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

However, when using VSTS (was Visual Studio Online) build, it now gives me the following error during the Package Restore step:

```
The project 'MyProject' does not specify any target frameworks in 'C:\a\1\s\MyProject\project.json'.
```

The command it shows executing is:

```
NuGet.exe restore "C:\a\1\s\Build.sln"  -NonInteractive -configfile "C:\a\1\NuGet\newNuGet.config"
```

Is this due to executing restore against a solution?  Or perhaps VSTS Build task is not yet using Nuget 3.4?

Comment: @EricLiu [`NETStandard.Library` 1.6.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/1.6.0) is the only release version of `NETStandard.Library` on NuGet. It's fine to depend on that even if you're using a lower version of `netstandard`.

Comment: I should mention that this is the project.json that was created by Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 after choosing the new "Target Net Standard Library" link in Project Properties.  I would be surprised if it was incorrect...

Comment: @EricLiu Yes, but that one is also perfectly fine for `netstandard1.0` projects. The release version != the target framework version. (It's silly that they look the same)

Answer (score 4):

You could expand Advanced section, and select latest version of Nuget. As of October 2016 that was Nuget 3.5 rc2

Comment: We use Nuget 3.5 rc2 (build 1829) but we still get the following error: ..\project.json(15,26): Error NU1001: The dependency NetStandard.Library >= 1.6.0 could not be resolved. When we try to run this version of Nuget locally and run dotnet build afterwards this works without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has been resolved already and you use the valid version of NuGet, but you can also add a command line as a new build step, just after the NuGet Installer, and invoke `dotnet restore` (Tool: `dotnet`, Arguments: `restore`).